# How to disable TLS handshake errors

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kube-apiserver

I'm getting lots of TLS handshake errors in my pods:

```
2023/04/19 05:06:38 http: TLS handshake error from 10.21.152.134:36134: EOF
```

as a result of a known issue introduced in go 1.17:

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/109022
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50984
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32406
```

Is there a way at least to suppress the logs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As this is a known issue, EOF errors seem to be related to a [Go bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50984) and appear on [Kubernetes 1.23 and 1.24](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/109022)  . This is not affecting any functional issues and these are generated from core kubernetes. We need to wait until a fix is suggested by kubernetes.   Can you try this work around to disable the TLS Handshake errors by following this [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) .

> This can be disabled  using ssl-redirect: "false" in the NGINX config
> map, or per-Ingress with the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect:
> "false" annotation in the particular resource.

Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889113/19230181) by Sathya for a workaround and [Gitlink](https://github.com/kyverno/kyverno/issues/6287) for any updates on the logs or Error disabling.